# AWS Security Group Meaning of Port 0 in Custom TCP Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I have a Custom TCP rule in Outbound Security Configuration with Port Range as 0. Does this 0 means it is open to all ports to the ip range provided in the rule?. I have faced  issues with this 0 as port when I changed this to correct port(5432) number after which it works fine.

Comment: A value of -1 in FromPort and ToPort indicates all ports.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are talking about the inbound rules (ingress) and outbound rules (egress) of a security group.  A security group being a firewall around an AWS component - in your case, as your using port `5432`, a PostgreSQL RDS database.

I just tested it on my side.  I had a working inbound rule for accessing an EC2 server.  When I changed the port to `0` - I could no longer access it.  If you were to allow inbound\outbound traffic to all the ports you would specify: `0-65535`

[image]

So as far as I can tell port `0` specified on its own doesn't seem to give any access.

Besides the `0-65535` port range, there is another valid port value when working with Cloudformation: `-1`.
This is used for the ICMP and ICMPv6 protocols.  Some mention of it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-fromport).
You can not specify `-1` as a port number when working with the AWS GUI.

If you are worried about security and just want to create an inbound rule for yourself - make sure to specify your `/32` CIDR as a suffix to the IP address as per the previous image where TCP access is given across all ports to someone at the `1.2.3.4` IP address.  Using a CIDR other than `/32` will allow access to other IP addresses O_O

If you are new to working with security groups also please note the following:

> Security groups are stateful - if you send a request from your
> instance, the response traffic for that request is allowed to flow in
> regardless of inbound security group rules. Responses to allowed
> inbound traffic are allowed to flow out, regardless of outbound rules.

In other words, don't create a possible security risk by unnecessarily duplicating inbound rules to outbound rules (or vica verca) if you mistakenly thought that you had to create a inbound\outbound rule to handle the responses to the allowed inbound\outbound traffic.

Comment: Thanks @Nico du Toit. I have faced this issue when using dblink to from one RDS to other RDS. AWS admin configured port 0 in outbound rule for the other RDS ip range . I was not able to connect and it throws connection timeout error and I changed it to 5432 then it works fine. Admin mentioned  0 is for all ports and I didnt see any reference to that so i asked here.

Comment: 0 doesn't mean it opens to all port. Specifying the exact port number or port range or ALL is the options.